# Não foi possível ativar o plugin porque ele gerou um erro fatal

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Estava tentando ativar meu plugin e este erro aparece no navegador na pagina de ativação do plugin do Wordpress (interface gráfica do mesmo), gostaria de saber onde posso ver este erro com mais informações sobre o motivo do mesmo.

O Sistema Operacional que utilizo é o Ubuntu;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para Visualizar os  erros no WordPress, primeiro você precisa mostra-los.

no arquivo wp-config.php vão ter as opções abaixo

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );

define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );

Marque a opção WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY como true, que assim que ativar seu plugin, ele mostrará o erro para você pelo menos saber por onde debuggar.